# Image path on Tomcat for Angular 7 application

Tags: angular, ubuntu, tomcat, deployment

I have problem with different image source paths for my local development on Windows machine (Windows 10, Visual Studio Code 1.30.2) and Tomcat 9 running on Ubuntu 18.04 server hosted on AWS. Built on Windows 10 in Powershell with:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /myapp/
```

BTW, if built with git bash it messes paths totally, don't do it.

If I want this app to work on local windows machine and if I want to have clickable (in VSCode) proper paths to image sources than I have to use:

index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

and in some component like: home.component.html

```
...
<img src="../../assets/data/avatar.png" width=100 />
...
```

But it want display images while deployed on Tomcat. I guess no issues with files permissions, as whole project was uploaded as content of 'dist' folder () to Linux server, then deployed through Tomcat UI manager. besides that, all other artifacts are loaded correctly.

So, to make it display in Tomcat I have to use:

index.html

```
<base href="./">
```

and in some component like: home.component.html

```
  ...
    <img src="assets/data/avatar.png" width=100 />
  ...
```

Haven't deployed for a while, but I don't recall there should be difference in relative paths in Windows vs Linux? Where did I go wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Once angular build the project, check the `dist` folder for the directory structure. You will notice that the `asset` directory is parallel to `index.html`. So you need to provide the path to your assets considering this directory structure.

So in your template you can refer to your assets as below -

```
<img src="./assets/data/avatar.png" width=100 />
```